# How to enable COVID-19 Exposure Logging in India

Tags: ios, ios13

How to enable Privacy => Health => COVID-19 Exposure Logging on a iPhone 6S+ device running 13.5.1 in India. Whatever Region I choose, it seems to be disabled and it mentions that its not enabled for the region.

We are developing an App using the Exposure Notification specification but aren't in a position to enable the above attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can only enable exposure logging if there is an app installed with the exposure logging entitlement.

Apple issues that entitlement to government agencies that are developing an exposure tracing app. In general, only one exposure tracing app is permitted per country.

If you are working for a government agency that is developing the official app for India then you need to apply for the entitlement though developer support. If you are not working for such an agency then you cannot have the entitlement and you cannot develop an exposure tracing app.

The process is described in the [Exposure Notification APIs Addendum](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/download/Exposure_Notification_Addendum.pdf)

> In order to use the Exposure Notification APIs, You must be a government entity, such as a government health services organization, or a developer who has been endorsed and approved by a government entity to develop an Application on behalf of a government for COVID-19 response efforts. Entitlement Profile(s) are limited to one (1) Application per country unless the country has a regional approach, or as otherwise agreed by Apple. If You are a developer who has been endorsed or approved by a government entity, You agree to provide documentation to Apple evidencing the authorization and endorsement of the government entity upon Apple’s request. Further, developers endorsed or approved by a government entity must have a written agreement with such government entity that obligates the government entity to abide by the terms of this Addendum and the Developer Agreement.